# Access Azure SQL Database from on premise network performance

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a VB.NET desktop solution that works with a SQL Server as database server.  When running locally or on a local network, the data queries run 1-2 seconds the most.  The same code when accessing an Azure Sql Database runs 15 to 30 seconds.  I have chosen a region as close as possible to the client's location, but this does not help.

What is the best way to improve the performance of this system?  Do I need to create a hybrid network or something of that effect?

I apologize in advance, I am not a network engineer and don't have much experience in fixing performance issues of this type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to keep in mind when comparing performance between SQL Azure and SQL Server:

- The number of round trips on the network matters more in SQL Azure if your client/app tier is not also in Azure.  If it takes 2ms round trip on-premises but 150ms round trip in your cloud example, the number of round trips can really add up quickly.  Sometimes the batch size can be made larger to hide some latencies to the data center from wherever you are running your client.
- There is also a decent chance that you did not really get the same query plans on SQL Server and SQL Azure and that this may be part of what you are seeing in the performance difference.  One way to get insight into the query plan choices in both cases is to use the query store (which is on-by-default in SQL Azure but can be enabled in SQL 2016+).  You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-operate-query-store.  There are also monthly releases of the SSMS client tool which has nice UI to navigate the query store.  You can download the most recent one  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).  When looking at performance of why a query performs differently, you first start by looking to see if the overall plan shapes are the same or not.  If they are different, then that might be the actual explanation for the performance difference.  If they are the same, then the next option is more likely the issue for you
- Finally, there are cases where customers are running SQL Azure with a very small reservation size (ex: Basic) and comparing it against their workstation or laptop in terms of performance.  Basic and Standard (S3 or so) databases are generally running on less than a core of CPU.  So, if you are trying to compare performance against your local machine, you need to remember that the reservation size can impact performance substantially as well.  Trying with a larger size (for testing) can help isolate whether this is the case or not.  If it is, there are various ways to improve performance of the query (indexing, considering how the query is written/what it is asking to see if there is a simpler way to represent things, etc) may be an option to improve the efficiency of the query to run efficiently enough in a smaller performance tier (to save money).

A broader explanation of why any generic query is slow in SQL is a much larger topic, so if you post some specifics from your investigation it may help people narrow down whether you have an indexing problem, something related to parameter sniffing, or one of the other more common pitfalls people hit when building SQL apps.

Best of luck - I hope this helps you take the next step to figure out your performance issue.

Comment: Thanks Conor.  I will follow your advise and will report back here.